# Swapping variables in python with a function

Tags: python, function

I need to write a program whose input is two integers and whose output is the two integers swapped.

If input is: `3 8`, output is `8 3`.

The program must define and call the following function. `swap_values()` returns the two values in swapped order.
`def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)`

so far I have:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    return user_val2, user_val1

user_val1 = int(input())
user_val2 = int(input())
swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)

print (swap_values(user_val1, user_val2))
```

but that produces `(8, 3)` and also doesn't work with a function call like `swap_values(-1, 10)`.

So I'm wondering what I would need to do to get `8 3` for the input and then `10 -1` for the function call.

Comment: You don't need a function for this. Just use: `user_val1, user_val2 = user_val2, user_val1`

Comment: Do you actually want to swap two variables (not possible in a python function), or do you just want to return the variables in a different order than they are given to the function (your current `swap_values`), or just print them out in a different order? (None of these are exactly the same thing.)

Comment: `swap_values` *returns* a new tuple; it doesn't reassign each argument to the other variable (which isn't possible in Python's semantic model).

Comment: Why do you have both `swap_values(...)` and `print(swap_values(...))`? As you have defined them, the latter should actually work: `print(swap_values(8,3))` should give `(3,8)`.

Comment: The print statement outputs `(8, 3)` because that's the string representation of the tuple `swap_values` returns.

Comment: Part of the assignment is to create a function. It looks like the issue is the printing. You can use formatted printing: `a,b = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2); print(f"{a} {b}")`

Comment: Johnny solved my formatting problem but it still doesn't work with a function call that changes the values for user_val1 and user_val2

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, many students will face difficulty with this lab because of a simple `if` statement which passes the unit tests that they are never told or taught to use.

```
def swap_values (user_val1 , user_val2):
    #Returns the two values in swapped order.   
    return user_val2 , user_val1 

# THIS IF STATEMENT MUST BE INCLUDED TO PASS UNIT TESTS.
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    user_val1 = int(input())  
    user_val2 = int(input())
    # user_val1 is assigned val2 and user_val2 with val1  
    user_val1, user_val2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2) 
    print(user_val1, user_val2)
```

The technique used in this approach involves returning two swapped variables in the `return` statement as a tuple, then unpacking them in the global namespace. It is a shame that the lab never mentions to use the `if` statement as it is not taught in this book up to this point.

Comment: The question doesn't actually mention a "lab" so I don't see how this actually answers the question. I get that you're doing some course that asks this problem, and OP probably was too, but what you've posted is pretty irrelevant to the question posted here

Comment: DavidW, The question doesn't mention a lab, but you can pretty much interpret it as so, especially since EVERY other post mentions it is a lab. In terms of not answering the OP question, OP asks how to swap variables in a function in Python. I answered this with an unpacking approach that meets the program requirements while supplying a summary of my actions along with in-line comments. I am open to ways I could be more direct with my answer, but I am confused on how my answer is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

### This is what I did for that same lab:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    swap = user_val1
    user_val1 = user_val2
    user_val2 = swap
    return user_val1,user_val2

user_val1 = int(input())
user_val2 = int(input())

user_val1, user_val2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)

print(user_val1, user_val2)
```

It worked fine in PyCharm and gave me the expected results, but zyBooks didn't like it and only gave be 2/10 credit. I reached out to the professor for help and they said I needed an if statement before the user_val inputs. I still can't figure out what the if statement should be though.

Comment: Seems the required `if` statement is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73436132/2745495) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70240395/2745495) answers.

Answer (score 1):

This question comes from a teaching website if anyone is wondering.

As far as I know, this LAB is impossible. If you format the return the way it says, the interpreter responds that there are too many packets when it calls the function, but if you do

```
return userVal1, userVal2
```

then it is not formatted correctly. If you are given this assignment by your teacher, contact them, do not waste time trying to get full points. Return either `x` or `y` in the following code to be correct because the unit tests x or y as the printed output.

```
def SwapValues(userVal1, userVal2):
    x = userVal2, userVal1
    y = '{} {}'.format(userVal2, userVal1)
    return x
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    print(SwapValues(input(), input()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did this lab and after some confusion, just unpacked the tuple so the output was formatted correctly.

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    return user_val2, user_val1

num1 = input()
num2 = input()
print(*swap_values(num1, num2))
```

The lab can also be done with fewer lines:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    return user_val2, user_val1
print(*swap_values(input(), input()))
```

Very bad lab that doesn't give you enough info for what it wants. There's not any mention of unpacking tuples this way in the material before it, and assigning the tuple to two new variables defeats the purpose of the lab. I'm not exactly sure what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the if statement to run as a script:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    swap = user_val1
    user_val1 = user_val2
    user_val2 = swap
    return user_val1,user_val2

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())

    user_val1, user_val2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)

    print(user_val1, user_val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is very simple:

```py
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    t = user_val1
    user_val1 = user_val2
    user_val2 = t
    return user_val1, user_val2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())
    user_val1, user_val2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)
    print(user_val1, user_val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I completed the lab recently, this was my code.

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    return user_val2, user_val1
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    user_val1 = (input())
    user_val2 = (input())
    swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)
    print(user_val2, user_val1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def swap_values(user_val1=None, user_val2=None):
    swap = user_val1
    user_val1 = user_val2
    user_val2 = swap
    return user_val1, user_val2

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())

    user_val1, user_val2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)

    print(user_val1, user_val2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, for the "function", all you really need is:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    return user_val2, user_val1
```

This effectively swaps the values on the return.

Answer (score -1):

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    return user_val2, user_val1
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    var1 = input()
    var2 = input()
    var1, var2 = swap_values(var1, var2)
    print(var1, var2)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this is correct, but it's what I used to pass the lab.  in the print statement I used this

```
print('{} {}'.format(val2,val1))
```